# vim 7.4.576: how does one delete and save to register with :g?

Tags: vim

How can one delete all lines matching a pattern and save them to a register for pasting them somewhere else in the file? I tried

```
:g/pattern/"xd
```

and

```
:g/pattern/normal "xd
```

The first one gave an error, while the second one didn't. However, with the second one, when I tried `"xp` I got the message that "register x is empty".

Thanks.

Comment: `:g/pattern/d X`

Comment: but you'll have to clear the `x` register before using this. Either `let @x=''` or `qxq`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, @Lieven didn't put this as an answer.

1. Clear register x with `qxq`.
2. Delete `pattern` into X (append) with `:g/pattern/d X`